# BODMAS Calculator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, calculator

I'm trying to create a calculator that follows the bodmas rule and trying first with multiplication. When the equals button is hit a string such as "4*5+6*7" is stored in displayValue. 
As a first attempt I use reg ex to search the string for the multiplication sign and it's position. When it finds the values to the lhs and rhs and stores that it cal. It then multiplies the values using firstValue, secValue and replaces cal with the result in displayValue. This works for 4*5, but I have to press equals again for it to do 6*7. I tried using a while loop but couldn't get it to work. How do I get it to do all the multiplication parts in the string in one go?

```
  equals() {
      const displayValue = this.state.displayValue.slice(0);
      let counter = displayValue.match(/[\d\.]+(?=\*)\*[\d\.]+/g).length;
      console.log("counter: " +counter);
      while (counter > 0) {
          let cal = displayValue.match(/[\d\.]+(?=\*)\*[\d\.]+/).toString().split("*").join(",");
           console.log("cal: " +cal)
           let operPos = cal.search(/\*/);
           let firstValue = parseFloat(cal.slice(0, operPos));
           let secValue = parseFloat(cal.slice(operPos + 1));
           let finalCal = firstValue * secValue;
           let result = displayValue.replace(/[\d\.]+(?=\*)\*[\d\.]+/, finalCal);
           this.setState({displayValue: result});
           counter = counter -1;
           console.log("counterII: " +counter)
       }
     console.log("new display: " +this.state.displayValue)
}
```

Comment: Please show an example of input and output.

Comment: you have one calculation (for two arguments), how can you expect more functionallity than coded? use loop/recurrence

Comment: @vivek when displayValue: 1*2-3*4, if I click equals the first time displayValue: 2-3*4, then I click equals again and displayValue: 2-12. What I want is to click equals once and displayValue goes from 1*2-3*4 to 2-12.

Comment: @Valerie so you want to evaluate step by step. I would suggest you to first parse all expressions that have `*` and `/` . So, the expression gets reduced to just operands and `+` and `-`. Now, reduce this too step by step.

Answer (score 0):

The displayValue was not updating in each loop because I assigned it as a const variable. Here's the correct code:

```
equals() {
    let displayValue = this.state.displayValue.slice(0);
    let counter = displayValue.match(/[\d\.]+(?=\*)\*[\d\.]+/g).length;
    console.log("counter: " +counter);
    while (counter > 0) {
        let cal = displayValue.match(/[\d\.]+(?=\*)\*[\d\.]+/).toString().split("*").join(",");
        console.log("cal: " +cal)
        let operPos = cal.search(/\*/);
        let firstValue = parseFloat(cal.slice(0, operPos));
        let secValue = parseFloat(cal.slice(operPos + 1));
        let finalCal = firstValue * secValue;
        displayValue = displayValue.replace(/[\d\.]+(?=\*)\*[\d\.]+/, finalCal);
        this.setState({displayValue: displayValue})
        console.log("result: " +displayValue)
        counter = counter -1;
        console.log("counterII: " +counter)
    }
}
```

If anyone has a better way to achieve the same thing please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `eval()` operation? Ex:

```js
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function(){
  let foo = eval("2*4*2");
  console.log(foo);//16
  return;
}
```

```html
<button id="clickMe">Click for Demo</button>
```

It can sometimes even parse a `function` too!
**EDIT:** This answer is no longer valid, as the asker intended to do step by step BEDMAS.
However, I will leave this on here for future readers.

Comment: This would directly give the final answer. OP wants it step wise as discussed in the comments. (P.S- I don't downvote).

Comment: Ok, I see. Will try to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a BODMAS based calculator using JavaScript

For full project :

https://github.com/theShaibaz/cool-projects/tree/master/Calculator%20(BODMAS)%20[JS]/Application%20Files

```
// +++++++++++++++++ //
// Sample Test Cases //
// +++++++++++++++++ //
// 10+20-30+40*5/2+10/5
// 10*20-30/40/5+2-10*5*9
// 10*20-30/40*5/2-10*5*0
// 10+20-30+40*5/2+10*5/5
// 10*20-30/40*5/2-10*5-87*2+115*111
// 10+20-30+40*5/(2+10*5)*5
// 10+20-(30+40)*5/2+(10*5)/5+(6+9)
// 10+20-(30+40*(10+10))*5/2+(10*5)/5+(6+9)
// 10+20-((30+40)*(10+10))*5/2+(10*5)/5+(6+9)
// ((14+11)+15*16-(13+10*11)+(10+10-(10*2)))
// 10+20-((30+40)*10+(10+(10*5))+10)
// 10+20-((30+40)*10+(10+(10*5+9)+9))+10
// 10+20-((30+40)*10+(10+(10+5))+10/(5*(10+10)))*5/2+(10*5)/5+(6+9+78/7)
// (10+20)-((30+40)*10+(10+(10+5)-(5+5))+(10/(5*(10+10)))*5/2+(10*5)/5+(6+9+78/7))

/// 10*(20-30/2)+40*5+2-(10*5+9)-(87*2+115*111)
/// 10*(20-30/2)+40*5+2-(10*5+9)*1-(87*2+115*111)
// console.log(eval(10*(20-30/2)+40*5+2-(10*5+9)-(87*2+115*111)))

function append(text) {
    document.getElementById("equation").value += text
}

function clearEquation() {
    document.getElementById("equation").value = ""
    document.getElementById("result").value = ""
}

function backspace(text) {
    document.getElementById("equation").value = text.substring(0, text.length - 1)
}

function startEvaluation(equation) {

    console.log(eval(equation))

    // var equation = prompt("Enter the equation")

    // Creating empty arrays for storing
    // brackets, operators, operands
    var brackets = []
    var operators = []
    var operands = []
    var operandString = ""


    for (var index = 0, operatorIndex = 0, bracketIndex = 0; index < equation.length; index++) {

        // Checking for operators
        if (equation.charAt(index) == '+'
            || equation.charAt(index) == '-'
            || equation.charAt(index) == '*'
            || equation.charAt(index) == '/') {

            // Below condition is to deal with (a+b)+(c+d) this part of equation
            if (equation.charAt(index - 1) == ')' && equation.charAt(index + 1) == '(') {
                operators[operatorIndex++] = "*"
                brackets[bracketIndex++] = null
                brackets[bracketIndex++] = null
                operators[operatorIndex++] = equation.charAt(index)
                operandString += " 1 "
            }
            // Fetching operators and storing into operators[] array
            else {
                operators[operatorIndex++] = equation.charAt(index)
                brackets[bracketIndex++] = null

                operandString += " "
            }
        }
        // Fetching brackets and storing into brackets[] array
        else if (equation.charAt(index) == '(' || equation.charAt(index) == ')') {
            brackets[bracketIndex++] = equation.charAt(index)
            operators[operatorIndex++] = null
        }
        // Fetching operand digits and storing into operandString
        else {
            operandString += equation.charAt(index)
        }
    }

    // Temp array of operands for further processing
    // before storing operands into operands[] array
    operandsTemp = operandString.split(" ")

    // Storing operands into operands[] array
    for (var index = 0, indexOperand = 0; index < operators.length; index++) {
        if (brackets[index] == null) {
            operands[index] = Number(operandsTemp[indexOperand++])
        }
        else {
            operands[index] = null
        }
    }
    operands[operands.length] = Number(operandsTemp[indexOperand])



    console.log(brackets)
    console.log(operators)
    console.log(operands)


    // Result variables
    var result = 0
    var finalResult = 0

    // Checking if brackets are present in the equation or not
    if (brackets.length > 0) {

        for (var index = 0; index < brackets.length; index++) {

            // Checking for occurance of closing bracket
            // and then searching for its corresponding
            // opening bracket by reverse traversing
            // and then evaluating that particular bracket equation
            // PROCESSES NESTED BRACKETS AS WELL
            if (brackets[index] == ')') {
                var indexBracketEnd = index
                for (var indexBracket = indexBracketEnd; indexBracket >= 0; indexBracket--) {
                    if (brackets[indexBracket] == '(') {
                        var indexBracketStart = indexBracket
                        evaluate(indexBracketStart, indexBracketEnd, operators, operands)
                        brackets[indexBracketStart] = null
                        brackets[indexBracketEnd] = null
                        break
                    }
                }
                console.log(brackets)
            }
        }
    }



    // This will evaluate remaining equation (without brackets)
    // after processing brackets (if available)
    finalResult = evaluate(0, operators.length, operators, operands)


    // FINAL RESULT
    console.log(`FINAL RESULT = ${finalResult}`)

    document.getElementById('result').value = finalResult
}

// Evaluation of equation by using BOAD MASS method
function evaluate(indexStart, indexEnd, operators, operands) {

    // First evaluating MULTIPLICATION and DIVISION
    for (var index = indexStart; index < indexEnd; index++) {

        var indexFirstOperand = index
        var indexNextOperand = index + 1
        var indexNextOperator = index

        if (operators[indexNextOperator] == null) {
            for (var indexNext = indexNextOperator + 1; indexNext < operators.length; indexNext++) {
                if (operators[indexNext] != null) {
                    indexNextOperator = indexNext
                    indexFirstOperand = indexNext
                    indexNextOperand = indexNext + 1
                    index = indexNext - 1
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if (operands[indexNextOperand] == null) {
            for (var indexNext = indexNextOperand + 1; indexNext < operands.length; indexNext++) {
                if (operands[indexNext] != null) {
                    indexNextOperand = indexNext
                    index = indexNext - 1
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        // MULTIPLICATION 
        if (operators[indexNextOperator] == '*') {
            result = operands[indexFirstOperand] * operands[indexNextOperand]

            operands[indexNextOperand] = result
            operands[indexFirstOperand] = null
            operators[indexNextOperator] = null
            finalResult = result
            result = 0

            console.log(operands)
            console.log(operators)
        }
        // DIVISION
        else if (operators[indexNextOperator] == '/') {
            result = operands[indexFirstOperand] / operands[indexNextOperand]

            operands[indexNextOperand] = result
            operands[indexFirstOperand] = null
            operators[indexNextOperator] = null
            finalResult = result
            result = 0

            console.log(operands)
            console.log(operators)
        }
    }

    // Next evaluating ADDITION and SUBSTRACTION
    for (var index = indexStart; index < indexEnd; index++) {

        var indexFirstOperand = index
        var indexNextOperand = index + 1
        var indexNextOperator = index

        if (operators[indexNextOperator] == null) {
            for (var indexNext = indexNextOperator + 1; indexNext < operators.length; indexNext++) {
                if (operators[indexNext] != null) {
                    indexNextOperator = indexNext
                    indexFirstOperand = indexNext
                    indexNextOperand = indexNext + 1
                    index = indexNext - 1
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if (operands[indexNextOperand] == null) {
            for (var indexNext = indexNextOperand + 1; indexNext < operands.length; indexNext++) {
                if (operands[indexNext] != null) {
                    indexNextOperand = indexNext
                    index = indexNext - 1
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        // ADDITION 
        if (operators[indexNextOperator] == '+') {
            result = operands[indexFirstOperand] + operands[indexNextOperand]

            operands[indexNextOperand] = result
            operands[indexFirstOperand] = null
            operators[indexNextOperator] = null
            finalResult = result
            result = 0

            console.log(operands)
            console.log(operators)
        }
        // SUBSTRACTION
        else if (operators[indexNextOperator] == '-') {
            result = operands[indexFirstOperand] - operands[indexNextOperand]

            operands[indexNextOperand] = result
            operands[indexFirstOperand] = null
            operators[indexNextOperator] = null
            finalResult = result
            result = 0

            console.log(operands)
            console.log(operators)
        }
    }

    // Returning FINAL RESULT
    return finalResult
}
```